# Forming the estimation manifold for a 2-D beamformer

Tags: estimation, beamforming, radio, multipath, multi-channel

Given an array of *L* sensors in a uniform planar array, with known positions in space, I would like to estimate both the angles of arrival and delays from a point source under multipath conditions simultaneously, initially using a Bartlett beamformer. The data from the array is in the frequency domain, taking the form of an *L* x *Nf* matrix, with *Nf* bins around a carrier frequency *f*.

Based on [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/630193), I have an *L* x *M* angular response vector *a*, and an *Nf* x *K* delay response vector *d*, where *M* and *K* are the resolutions in angle and delay respectively. From these, I wish to create an estimation manifold (defined as U in the paper), which will become the 2-D analogue of the array response vector in the case of 1-D beamforming.

From equation 1 in the paper, it appears as if I need to set M = K, with their product becoming the estimation manifold U, however this produces a level surface when plotted. Alternatively, letting M != K and taking the Kronecker product means this manifold will quickly grow beyong a reasonably storable size, especially when *M*, *K* or *L* are large.

I have also tried slicing the input data into *L* x 1 slices and treating this as a 1-D estimation problem, which was then projected into 2-D using the delay response vector *d*, however as this removes the temporal relationships, this did not yield relevant results either.

Is there a better way of forming this estimation manifold, and eventually applying it to a Bartlett beamformer?

Also, for full disclosure this is part of university coursework.

Comment: You might want to duplicate the equation 1 here as it is behind a paywall.  That way more people could potentially answer.

Comment: Could you mathematically write down what you like to solve for? There could be interested audience who are not really familiar with beamforming.